# database model: group similar images together

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I've created a db in mySQL that stores many things, but specially images. The table name for storing the images is `image`, like so:

```
image (image_id, title, caption, filename, published_date, ...)
```

It's been almost 2 years and i've uploaded almost 5000 images into the table.

Now, i want to add a new functionality. I want to group similar images so when im looking at an image, i can also have the option to look at images that are similar.

I'm not sure if i need a new table or should i use the same table or both. Any ideas/suggestions on how it should be?

Comment: What do you mean by "similar?"

Comment: Most likely, the logic to determine if two images be similar would happen outside of MySQL.  Also, "similar" is a very relative thing and depends on what you measure of similarity is.  I'm not sure you even need to change your database design.

Comment: @Difster I'm going to manually group images myself.

Comment: I took the liberty to edit the question and add the `database-design` tag.

Comment: Upload to Google and tag them.  It can do the rest.

Answer (score 2):

You should create another table with that similiarities.

Why can't it be the same table ? One record in You table can have many similiar records (so it will be adding many columns to that table  or for every similiarity there will be another row in YOur table. So the only logical option is to create another table.

```
IdFromMainTable | IdOfSimiliarRecord
```

Later on You can show that similiarites in a view easily joining that table by IdFromMainTable. Or both IdOfSimiliarRecord and IdFromMainTable. [depends if u want to add 2 records for similiar records or just one for similiar pair]

Comment: @Marco An upvote from me. Alternatively you can have a different table for tags or keywords and a many-to-many table modeling the image-tag relationship. Granted, there will be joins, but this will also make searching for "similar" images easier. In any case you should go with this, relational, approach. Stuffing such info in the original table is a quick-and-seamingly-easy, but eventually really painful, way.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you want to do is create tags for the images. There are a number of ways to do that, but adding the tags to the same table would prevent a whole lot of joins from taking place and would likely be faster. You could just store the tags as JSON (if you're using MySQL =>7.5.8).

Comment: you mean mysql 5.7.18 ?

Comment: [The documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html)  says 5.7.8

Comment: Searching for similar images will certainly not be faster this way. Relational modelling will do the job here.